# Problems with Mixed content: an insecure script requested

Tags: https, google-analytics, mixed-content, goal-tracking

I have problems with setting up goals in Google Analytics. There are a few bugs in the order page, which I think are causing the problem. With the help of GA debug extention I managed to reach the following errors (5) and warnings (4):

(Here are only the errors, unfortunately 2 as I am not allowed to post more than two links)

-> Mixed Content: The page at ''https://www.xxx.de/de/xxx/'' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://delivery.fpmserving.com/tag.php?tag_id=53&campaign_id=32'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

-> Mixed Content: The page at 'the same as above' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'the same as above'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Furthermore, the Page source could not load.

Is there any way that I could remove this insecure script? And make sure that the content is served over HTTPS?

PS: I am not a Developer and unfortunately I am not really familiare with HTML and HTTPS, although I try to inform myself!

Comment: This looks like a campaign tracking tag, only that fpmserving.com seems defunct. Ask your technician to remove that tag asap (that warning will cost you money when clients leave your site - as they should, since unsecure elements in the page effectively break ssl encryption. Plus you are sending data to an unknown third party which is probably illegal under german law).

Comment: Plus while your privacy policy states that IP anonymization is active in Google Analytics this is not actually the case, and that's defintively not legal (and misinformation makes it worse).

Comment: Incidentally you might consider to remove this question, because "there is stuff in my page that I don't know about and that breaks my ssl encryption" is not something you want at the top spot in a Google search for your business. At least edit out the urls.